# Is it possible to define a property with Class type that conforms to protocol?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category, objective-c-protocol

For example, I have `MyFancyData` protocol. How can I specify that MyFancyDataClass property accepts only classes that conforms to this protocol.

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property Class MyFancyDataClass;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@property id<MyFancyData> myFancyDataClass;
```

Comment: `myFancyDataClass` is object of class that conforms to MyFancyData. But I need an object of `Class` type.

Comment: id basically means any class. So it will work. Or you can use Object<MyFancyClass>

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) Class<MyFancyData> cls;
@end
```

Comment: No, I need a property of Class type.

Comment: It works, but it seems like it don't change anything. I still can set object of any class to this property.

Comment: You can set an object? That's a class property.

Comment: I can set a Class that don't conforms to protocol specified in property definition.

Comment: I guess it won't get any better than this.

Comment: @Andy: Feel free to post a solution.

Comment: I've decided to use this approach for my needs: `- (id<MyFancyData>) getNewMyFancyDataObject;`. This way I'll get compile warnings if something wrong.