# Define property type in a class implementing protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know that the question title is not perfectly clear but I don't know how to better explain my doubt.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760662/is-it-possible-to-define-a-property-with-class-type-that-conforms-to-protocol) but my problem is slightly different:

If I use "generic" id then I lose information about the object I put in the variable and I don't have compile time issue about wrong data types, so I need to change id to NSString for specific classes.

The point is:
Protocols are meant to be generic, so, if I define a protocol with this property:

```
@protocol MyProtocol
   @property (nonatomic,strong) id aVariable;
@end
```

Then I create a class like this:

**.h**

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <MyProtocol>
[...]
```

**.m**

```
@implementation MyClass
  @syntetise aVariable = _aVariable;
  [...]
@end
```

**The question is:** Since I want that the class "MyClass" has a specific type for `aVariable` (example NSString) **how can I change the type of the protocol's variable implementation for specific classes?**

I hope to be more clear with the question now. :)

Comment: I don't think protocols are meant to be generic. A protocol defines a contract between two ore more classes.

Comment: `Protocols are meant to be generic`. It's not true. objective-c doesn't have generics or something looks like generics. That's why we have just `NSArray` instead `NSArray<NSString>`. If you need generics so hard, you can look at objective-c++'s templates. But you also will not be able create `NSArray<NSString>`.

Comment: I know. I didn't write "generic" as "informatic point of view" but as "unrelated to a specific class".